# Velocity giving parsing exception for hyphen present in normal string

Tags: java, templates, velocity, apache-velocity

For the string `#TestString (test-string this is random string)`, the velocity engine while evaluating throws following parsing exception.

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "-" at PERSONALISATION[line 1, column 18]
Was expecting one of:
    <RPAREN> ...
    <WHITESPACE> ...
    <WHITESPACE> ...
```

Velocity 1.7 is being used, and the context passed while evaluating is empty except the Escape Tool.

```
VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
velocityContext.put("esc", new EscapeTool());
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
getVelocityEngine().evaluate(velocityContext, writer, "TEST-TEMPLATE", text);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Velocity, the directives begin with `#` like `#if`, `#foreach`, etc. The `#` at the beginning of the line makes Velocity think that `#TestString` is a directive and so after it encounters the open parenthesis, it is looking for a closing parenthesis and encounters the `-` instead. Hence the parsing error. Something like `#TestString(test)`, `#TestString('test-string this is random string')` or `TestString#` wouldn't cause any parsing errors. If your rendered string needs to look exactly like `#TestString (test-string this is random string)`, you can use something like the below:

```
#set($hash = '#')
${hash}TestString (test-string this is random string)
```